# How can I route between different network using multiple ethernet card?

Tags: networking, network-manager, ethernet, routing

I have two ethernet card in the PC, eth0 is connected to the local network(192.168.0.0/24), and the other is connected to the internet. I can reach all the devices which are connected to this interface.

However there is a second ethernet card (eth1) which is connected to the internet, however I have no connection through the internet,  when I unplug eth0 then the internet is back. I suppose this is a routing problem, however I am wondering how can I fix this?

Comment: For your eth0, there may not be a `Default subnet` declared. Your computer uses this as the internet gateway, and if there's no internet, it cannot connect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into "Setting up a Gateway in Debian/Ubuntu", if you want to allow other machines on the LAN to access the Internet.

#### Simple, single-machine setup

Read **Notes** and put Internet on eth0.  `reboot` and see if it is magically working.  If not...

1. `route add host 192.168.0.1 eth1`
2. `route add --net 192.168.0.0/24 gw 192.168.0.1`

#### Notes

1. Your default gateway and up-channel default to eth0.

   - Your Internet should be on eth0
   - Your LAN should be on eth1 (assuming ip of 192.168.0.1 for router)
   - Your LAN/eth1 should have a static or dhcp ip setup in `/etc/networking`
2. You may want to use `bind` for routing/dns

   - Sometimes, this is called `named`
3. You may want to use `dhcpd` for DHCP

#### References

1. [IP Forwarding from Linux PC](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/13029/ip-forwarding-from-linux-pc/13042#13042)
2. [Debian Router Gateway in 15 Minutes](http://blog.noviantech.com/2010/12/22/debian-router-gateway-in-15-minutes/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I don't want other machine to get access to the network, I just want this single PC to get access to both network.

Comment: Try the **Simple, single-machine setup** and let us know if you get it working :D